# jQuery Get element by name and do action on Key "Enter"

Tags: jquery, onclick, key, enter

I hope you can help me with this.
I have an element, a button input that has not an ID but only a name.

I am working on a CMS and I do not want to modify the default code.

I am wondering if there is in jQuery a function that will give me the possibility to get an Element by name instead than by ID.

I want to add an `onClick` function to this element, so I need a way to get its name instead of the ID.

The other question is if there is a way in jQuery that I can use to run a function when <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the keyboard is pressed on a input text element. Something like `onClick`, but when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed.

Let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes...

1) You can get the element by name using the [attribute equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector) selector:

```
$('button[name="foo"]')
```

where `foo` is your element's name.

2) The click handler will automatically be run if you press enter if the element is an anchor (link) element.  Otherwise, use [`keypress`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress) and compare [`event.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which) (the numeric identifier for the key that was pressed) to `13` (which indicates the enter key):

```
$('button[name="foo"]').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        // the enter key was pressed
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an attribute equality selector.

```
$('input[name="foo"]').click(function(){});
```

---

On the second part, you'll need to add an event handler for keydown.

```
$('input[name="textfield"]').keydown(function(evt){
  if ((evt.keyCode) && (evt.keyCode == 13))
  {
     // perform enter actions.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="myName"]').click(function() {
    //do whatever
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Get Element by name attribute:

```
$("[name='elementName']").click(function(){
  //perform action
});
```

Run code when enter is pressed in an input field:

```
$('input[type="text"]').bind("keypress", function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13){
                //run enter code
            }
        });
```